# typescript Generic Function that inherit T

Tags: typescript, prototype, typescript-typings

I am to trying add a method to `Function`.

The problem is that the return value dose not automaticlly inherit T.

```js
interface Function {
  Promise <T> (...args: any[]): Promise<T> ;
}

Function.prototype.Promise = async function <T> (this: Function , ...args: any[]): Promise <T> {
  return new Promise <T> ((resolve, reject) => {
    this(args).then((x: T) => resolve(x)).catch((e: any) => reject(e));
  });
}
```

```js
  var test =(async()=> {
      return "";
  });
  // this return Promise<unknown> it should return Promise<string>
  test.Promise() 
  
  
  
  // this should work, but I want the above to work instead 
  // it should inherit the type automaticly
   test.Promise<string>()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture the type of the function that was invoked using the `this` parameter. You can also capture the type of the parameters and the return type to better type the resulting function.

```
interface Function {
  Promise<TReturn, TArgs extends any[]>(this: (...a: TArgs) => Promise<TReturn>, ...a: TArgs): Promise<TReturn>;
}

Function.prototype.Promise = async function <TReturn, TArgs extends any[]>(this: (...a: TArgs) => Promise<TReturn>, ...args: TArgs): Promise<TReturn> {
  return new Promise<TReturn>((resolve, reject) => {
    this(...args).then((x: TReturn) => resolve(x)).catch((e: any) => reject(e));
  });
}

var test = (async () => {
  return "";
});
// this return Promise<unknown> it should return Promise<string>
test.Promise()
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIFcQLMA9iZAbwChlkAFKXAW2AGcIAeAFQCUIx0oQAaZZgIJQA5nWQQAHpBAATMXBABPANoBdAHwAKMAAt6ALmSaAdKbiHBIugEpkAXnUUqtBi3adu6vqePn+Q0WtDShp6JjYOLhB1AG5iAF9iYgwsHHxjAAcqMFwwRQyIYxCXFDtkODpFLGQYTGw8AjdI7j5LUXEpCFl5JTUtXQMjHz82m3tHYrCmj2jvMysLAJtg5ymImccSMihmghAIAHcnUNd1qK1NHbpcABsANwg+HYArCGxbByJSMmQBuhN5oFjLouppNBILO4oh9HFdbg9wdZrMYEHAwAgdGCIIYFIoYcgXm8wJoIEi4mR4tY4oliHc4FBfhA6GB7EYKlUEEZ8VsCbtkAAifnUqnEAD0ot+ejEOxmxxKjEwAGsQLgDtFkMAWXQdLh0DcZLzZZNXMyoKBhOpiJBmUVVgxNLYgA)

Comment: That did the trick thx